# Remote monitoring on MobaXterm

Tags: cpu-usage, monitoring, top, mobaxterm, zabbix

There is a remote monitoring bar at the bottom of the MobaXterm. That's very cool and it is near real-time.
[image]

I wish I could full-screen the CPU utilization chart, but it is not possible. A similar wish is true for RAM utilization.
Does anybody know how to reach these real-time utilization charts in an agent-less manner? like how MobaXterm extracts these graphs. By bash, by python, or any other tools. I set up a Zabbix server, but it is not able to give a near real-time utilization graph.

Comment: Have to tried running the `top` utility?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, the top and the htop don't draw a real-time chart for utilization (utilization as Y-axis and time as X-axis)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by enabling "Remote-monitoring(experimental)"

- Settings -> Configuration -> SSH
- Select "Remote-monitoring"
- Click OK